# PHP Add Hour to beginning of day

Tags: php

Given a date and an hour, I want to append that hour onto that date.

E.g: Given hour 3 and date 2017-05-30 I want: 2017-05-30 03:00:00

```
<?php

$d1 = date('Y-m-d');
$hour = 3;
$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+' . $hour .' hours', $d1));
echo $new_time;

?>
```

When running the following code I get:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered on $new_time =
>   date("Y-m-d H:i:s...

How can I get the proper output?

Comment: Do you want 3 hours from now, or just `03:00:00` of that date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try strtotime() with + hour like below :

```
<?php
    $d1 = date('Y-m-d');
    $new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($d1."+ 3 hour")); //here you can change the hour according to your need as now it is + 3
    echo $new_time;
```

Comment: *"@Apparently Im user2212428"* - I think that's understood ;-)

Comment: Yeah I noticed you tag the OP in all the answers you're giving (not just this one). You dont have to do that. It's already implied that an answer on Stackoverflow is a reaction to the question.

Comment: @Loko probably his *"signature"* lol

Comment: wonder what'll happen if and when all of those OP's change their profile names lol!!! they'll be wondering who you're talking to haha!

Comment: now i think its fine m i right ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Given that he has 1380 reputation, he probably knows no one tags OP in an answer, but he still does it so it probably is his "signature". I've also noticed he starts every answer with:"@user try this:" and thats it.

Comment: @Loko Right... and like I said in an above comment;, about if and when someone changes their profile name lol

Comment: @ Loko yeah this is my signature man

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah exactly, the intro of the answer would make no sense in that case.

Comment: @BunkerBoy Loko didn't get that ping; you've a space after the @

Comment: what is wrong with tagging the OP name in the answer ?

Comment: @BunkerBoy I already addressed that twice which could happen and it does happen that people change their profile names. It's also not needed.

Comment: let it finish buddy i'll remember to  Fred -ii- ok ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Datetime](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) and add [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php):

```
$now = new DateTime(); //current date/time
$now->add(new DateInterval("PT3H"));
$new_time = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $new_time;
```

DateInterval receives as parameter a string, if you want to learn more about the way you can format the intervals check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the time that you need to add by `strtotime($time) + $yourtimeinseconds;`

Here's the [Eval Link](https://eval.in/807879)

Code :

```
<?php
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$hour = 3*60*60; // To Seconds
$time = strtotime($time) + $hour; // Add 1 hour
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time); 
echo $time;
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers are for if you want 3 hours from the current time. If you just want 3am, then just append the time, no math necessary.

```
$time = date('Y-m-d 03:00:00');
```